# How to select distinct value from array items in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Currently, I want to display all value from list items but I want to remove duplicate value and only showing the unique value to user.

I tried to implement as below code but it doesn't work .

```
<tr>
<td class="col-ss1 col1">Currency</td>
<c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
<td class="col-ss1 "><c:forEach items="${item.terms}" var="term" varStatus="mainLoop">
    <c:if test="${(mainLoop.index - 1) > 0}">
        <c:forEach var="previousTerm" items="${item.terms}" begin="0"
        end="${mainLoop.index-1}" varStatus="inner">
    <c:if test="${term.currencyType == previousTerm.currencyType }">
        <c:set var="flag" value="true"/>
    </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not flag}">${term.currencyType }</c:if>
</c:forEach></td>
</c:forEach>
<!-- <td class="col-ss1 col2">VNĐ / USD / EURO</td>
<td class="col-ss1 col3">VNĐ / USD / EURO</td>
<td class="col-ss1 col4">VNĐ / USD / EURO</td>
<td class="col-ss1 col5">VNĐ / USD / EURO</td> -->
```

Comment: I really think you should do clear the list in the controller (or even in the business logic), not in the JSP.

Comment: why not use Set rather than List to remove duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I also agree with y , we should do in the controller but because of logic code in our project, we have to implement in jsp file, I appriciate your help in this case. Thanks

Comment: user23123412 : Please explain more detail ....thanks

Comment: Set seems to handle in Controller too. Have you try to add a local variable to re-structure listProducts, and use the variable for loop?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible since EL 3.0 with the EL Stream API introduced as part of [Collection Operations](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/5.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-5.0#collection-operations) feature. EL 3.0 is part of Java EE 8 / Servlet 4.0 which was introduced in Sep 2017. It's available since Tomcat 9.x, WildFly 14.x, GlassFish/Payara 5.x, etc.

The EL Stream API supports the [`distinct()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/5.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-5.0#distinct) function which you can use to remove duplicates.

Therefore your approach can be rewritten as follows:

```xml
<c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="item">
    <td>
        <c:forEach items="${item.terms.stream().map(term -> term.currencyType).sorted().distinct().toList()}" var="currencyType">
            ${currencyType}<br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommanded to do this on the server side, in a java class...

```
List<String> yourListContainingDublicates...
Set<String> uniqueElementsSet = new HashSet<String>(yourListContainingDublicates)
```

The HashSet constructor identifies duplicates by invoking the elements' equals() methods.

Comment: Yes, but you want to me to write the above code in jsp file ?

Comment: Of course not, you should do this on server side, you create a new list from the set to not break you code in jsp, or use the toArray() method from Set. And in jsp <c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
use the new list.

Comment: Yes,I see you idea and  I also agree with y , we should do in the controller but because of logic code in our project, we have to implement in jsp file, I appreciate your help in this case. Thanks

Comment: I am still looking for the best way to do it...:)

Comment: if you must do this in the jsp, then the best thing is to create a scriplet before the <c:forEach... tag, and create the set there, and in the <c:forEach... tag use the uniqueElementsSet.toArray() method of Sets interface. In this way you have a much cleaner code, easier to read...

Comment: Thanks, I am trying but it would be grateful if you can explain more detai..:)

Comment: <%
   Set<String> uniqueElementsSet = new HashSet<String>(listProducts);
%>


<c:forEach items="${uniqueElementsSet.toArray()}" var="item" varStatus="loop">

Comment: Thanks Aurelianus, I will try

Comment: you might need to add this set to pageContext in the scriptlet...

pageContext.setAttribute("uniqueElementsSet", uniqueElementsSet);

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample code for your reference

```
public class MyDisticntElements {


public static void printDistinctElements(int[] arr){

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        boolean isDistinct = false;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                isDistinct = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isDistinct){
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String a[]){

    int[] nums = {5,2,7,2,4,7,8,2,3};
    MyDisticntElements.printDistinctElements(nums);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar problem where I had to use only JSTL to remove the duplicate entries and I decided to modify your piece of code and it seems to be working fine for me. You can try this one:

```
<c:forEach items="${listProducts}" var="item" varStatus="loop"><td class="col-ss1 ">
   <c:forEach items="${item.terms}" var="term" varStatus="mainLoop">
        <c:set var="flag" value="false"/>
        <c:forEach var="previousTerm" items="${item.terms}" begin="${mainLoop.index+1}" varStatus="inner">
            <c:if test="${term.termName eq previousTerm.termName }">
                <c:set var="flag" value="true"/>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${not flag}">
            ${term.currencyType }
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach></td>
</c:forEach>
```